# Firebase: Function Triggers: A function used to work, now fails with "CANCELLED: The operation was cancelled."

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-vision

I built this function months ago and has been working fine until two days ago, after updating Flutter (unrelated I presume). The function essentially reviews a users upload photo for inappropriate content before moving the documents for the public to see.

I can see the images and documents uploading correctly from app to Firestore. This then triggers the function which uses vision.ImageAnnotatorClient() to label the images ('@google-cloud/vision'). Almost immediately the function console throws this error:

```
onCreatePost:
Error: 1 CANCELLED: The operation was cancelled.
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:30:26)
    at Http2CallStream.call.on (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:96:33)
    at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
    at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at process.nextTick (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:97:22)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

1. At what level is this cancellation occuring? I don't even know where to narrow down my search to.
2. How did this happen? Can I expect random functions to fail in the future?
3. Am I taking crazy pills? Feels like i'm going crazy looking for material on this.

Edit: 
I have narrowed the error down to this line in my function:

```
var [dataTest] = await visionClient.annotateImage(request)
```

visionClient being an instance of vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
vision coming from '@google-cloud/vision'

I also noticed that these errors started appearing after an unusual unique error:

```
onCreatePost
Error: function crashed out of request scope Function invocation was interrupted.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72853273/14206384

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue:

I had to go into my Flutter apps functions folder, where I hold my firebase cloud functions. I then had to update 'google-cloud/vision' using the following command:

```
npm install --save @google-cloud/vision
```

I deployed the new update to firebase and everything started working again... How am I supposed to catch updates on packages like this changing and breaking my code?